# Hosted Payment Gateways and Hidden Field Tampering

Tags: e-commerce, field, hidden, payment

I am in the midst of trying to find an e-commerce solution for my employer, and it is necessary that we go with a hosted payment page to minimize our PCI compliance woes. After researching several companies' solutions, it seems that they all expect you to submit the total price of the transaction to them via a hidden field or GET variables in order to generate the payment form. This seems like a sizable concern for the merchant, since a user with Firebug (or eyes, in the case of GET variables) could easily modify the transaction total, get a new hosted payment form, and continue with the checkout, thus giving themselves whatever discount they desire.

Has anyone set up a hosted payment page before and dealt with this issue? Any suggestions for a better way to do things?

Answer (score 2):

There usually is a hash submitted with those forms that are generated with secret values that the user won't know (e.g. password, transaction key, etc). So if they tamper with the amount, which is also used in calculating the hash's value, then the payment gateway will reject the transaction. The user cannot bypass this by changing the hash because they do not have all of the information required to calculate it.

So using these hosted forms are safe from abuse. If they weren't they wouldn't be viable products and the gateways couldn't offer them for use.

Comment: If you are referring to the hosted form itself being secure, I'm not disputing that. My issue is that, in order to have them generate a form for my transaction, I have to first pass them the total price of the transaction, and that is where the tampering can happen: before the hosted form is generated.

Comment: The hash is generated when you send the user to the payment gateway's hosted form. So it is generated **after** the total is calculated and **before** the user is sent to the hosted form.

Comment: After doing some research into Authorize.net's solutions (which you appear to have experience with) I see that they do support what you've described. However, many other payment processors, such as Moneris (whom my employer has chosen to go with), do not seem to support any kind of hash submission, hence my confusion. Really seems like a basic feature they all should provide...

Comment: If they don't provide it there must be some kind of mechanism is place to prevent fraud. If there isn't would be shocked that they would be allowed to continue to offer it as a product. But stranger things have happened.